# Playwright Python Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, python, playwright

I run 300 asyncio tasks, with multiple browsers contexts that visit pages at the same time. Sometimes I get this error which causes everything to crash. From what I understand, this is either a memory leak or just not having enough resources available. I am not sure whether it is a memory leak caused by me, since there is not much I am doing on my side (just visiting webpages, and yes, I do close pages after visit is completed). What happens if there is a memory leak in the JavaScript code executed by visiting one of the web pages? Is there a way to make Playwright avoid letting a webpage consume all the resources?

```
[240854:0x6785e40]  1640109 ms: Mark-sweep 4016.8 (4131.1) -> 4004.4 (4131.8) MB, 2680.4 / 0.4 ms  (average mu = 0.086, current mu = 0.041) task; scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb7a940 node::Abort() [/home/Traffic/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/driver/node]
(...)
```